# how to place text on fraction for accounting formulas?

Tags: math-operators, fractions

Sorry for the bad grammar. English is not my native language.

I want to have text on a fraction type line to show up in an accounting formula, here's an example of what I want:

[image]

So, I've tried using the math way with `\frac` but I end up whit so many errors. Is there a specific way to put text on the `\frac` code ? Or is there a specific code to put text on a fraction?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you `\usepackage{amsmath}` then in math mode (in particular, inside `\frac`) you can use `\text{VP Beneficios}` to get text. If you want white space you need to include it: `\text{ VP Beneficios }`

Comment: As simple it look it solved all my problems, thx so much!! for those who have the same problem and want a example here it is:


\begin{equation}
B/C={\frac{\text{VP Beneficios}}{\text{VP de Costos}}}={\frac{\text{VA de Beneficios}}{\text{VA de Costos}}}={\frac{\text{VF de Beneficios}}{\text{VF de Costos}}}
\end{equation}

Comment: If all you have are text fractions, it's convenient to define `\newcommand{\textfrac}[2]{\frac{\text{#1}}{\text{#2}}}` so that you can use `\textfrac{VA de Beneficios}{VA de Costos}`.