# problem on the parentheses direction in equations

Tags: equations, amsmath

I recently installed a MacTex version and I faced a problem with the direction of parentheses both in the enumeration and the text reference using `\eqref`. I use XeLaTeX to compile the `tex` files. Since in my tex file I have right-to-left content, I have to use the bidi package.

Example:

Precision is computed as in equation )3.3(.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\Farsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}
\usepackage{fontspec}\newfontfamily\Parsifont[Script=Arabic]{XB Kayhan}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\ARL}[1]{\RL{\Farsifont #1}}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\begin{document}

Precision is computed as in equation \eqref{eq:precision}.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:precision}
P = \frac{Number~of~Correct~Constituents}{Total~Number~of~Constituents~in~Parser~Output}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

How can the parentheses be reordered in the correct format?

Comment: Please provide an executable MWE.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What a nice question! I'm curious to see the reason and the solution. +1

Comment: To put them in the correct format (which is the default) you need to not do whatever you did to put them in that format, so you need to show the code that produces that. Is the main text of your document Right to Left by any chance?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i think the r-to-l conjecture is right on.  since `\eqref` is involved, this says `amsmath` to me, and i'd love to have a good (non)working example for testing.

Comment: I added the code to my question.

Comment: How can I have the correct ordering while the bidi package is used? I did not have the problem before my update.

Comment: Not an answer but ... for text in math mode, consider http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/how-to-place-text-on-fraction-for-accounting-formulas/80167#80167

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84293/amsmath-bidi-siunitx-possible-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is essentially the same as that in [amsmath - bidi - siunitx possible bug?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84293/15925) and Joseph Wrights solution there works here too.  Additionally, you setting of the text in mathematics, in particular with `~`, is not correct, producing error messages.  Normally I would write such text chunks in `\text`, but in this situation you might choose the solution below with `\mathit` and space written as `\`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[oneside, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newcommand{\ARL}[1]{\RL{\Farsifont #1}}
\newcommand{\PRL}[1]{\RL{\Parsifont #1}}

\csname @Latintrue\endcsname

\begin{document}

Precision is computed as in equation \eqref{eq:precision}.

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:precision}
P = \frac{\mathit{Number\ of\ Correct\ Constituents}}{\mathit{Total\
Number\ of\ Constituents\ in\ Parser\ Output}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you used `\textit` instead of `\mathit` in the two parts of the fraction, you could dispense with the explicit `\ ` (space) directives...

Comment: That is essentially what I meant by saying "normally I would write such chunks in `\text`".  However, the `\mathit` version may be more appropriate inside some right-to-left material, where mathematics still has to be left-to-right.  We don't really have enough context from the poster.