# Align math explanation

Tags: spacing

Any possibility to align the fractions (units in general) too?

```
Wobei:
\begin{flalign*}
\noindent \tab \rho _{KOH} & = 2.04 \frac{g}{cm^3} &\\
M_{KOH} & = 56.10 \frac{g}{mol} &\\
c_{KOH} & = 0.05 \frac{mol}{L} &\\
\end{flalign*}
```

If I add another & they end up completely at the right.

Comment: @EthanBolker How would I insert fractions within `text` then?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/how-to-place-text-on-fraction-for-accounting-formulas/80167#80167 - or either of the answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode = fraction]{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\rho_{\ch{KOH}} &=  &  2.04\,&\si{\g\per\cubic\cm} \\
   M_{\ch{KOH}} &={}& 56.10\,&\si{\g\per\mol}      \\
   c_{\ch{KOH}} &=  &  0.05\,&\si{\mol\per\L}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Note: It's a guess that "KOH" is a chemical formula; if not, remove the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package and write `\textup{KOH}` instead of `\ch{KOH}`.

Comment: It might be a bit more in keeping with the syntax of the `siunitx` package if you wrote `\SI{2.04}{\gram\per\cubic\centi\meter}` instead of `\num{2.04} \,&\frac{\si{\g}}{\si{\cubic\cm}}`, etc. -- and loaded the package with the option `per-mode = fraction`, of course.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that part. Your solution works like a charm for that.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped a lot! I guess indenting it wouldn't be a problem. And yes KOH is potassium hydroxide.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I finally got around to test your code however I can't get it left-aligned or left-aligned with an indent.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg As far as I know all equations will be left aligned then. I would like my equations centered and my explanation for the values left aligned with an indent.

Answer (score 3):

This uses the (in progress) `tabstackengine` package (introduced at [Writing a table with equally spaced columns, based on the widest column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139771/writing-a-table-with-equally-spaced-columns-based-on-the-widest-column/139946#139946), source code at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)).  I really need to finish up the documentation to release the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{1.5ex}
\begin{document}
\noindent Wobei:
\par\medskip\noindent\tabbedShortstack[l]{
\rho _{KOH} &= 2.04 &\frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{cm}^3} \\
M_{KOH} &= 56.10 &\frac{\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{mol}} \\
c_{KOH} &= 0.05 &\frac{\mathrm{mol}}{\mathrm{L}} \\
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitly look at the tabstack engine however from a first glance I prefer @Svend 's solution.

Comment: I wanted to try your engine however it seems as it is not released yet. Anyway to subscripe to you to get informed on release?

Comment: @idkfa You can copy the source code (tabstackengine.sty) at the link provided in my answer.  I have no way to automatically alert you when I get around to releasing it, however, if I am able to remember, I will send a comment your way.  Thanks for your interest.