# Unit spacing with siunitx in an equation

Tags: spacing, equations, siunitx, units

I'm just starting to get to grips with the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package, but I've noticed that there seems to be some issues with regards to unit notation spacing in an equation.  With `siunitx` it is possible to put a space between the numerical value and the unit by leaving a space after the number of before the unit (e.g., `\num{3.7d10} \si{\becquerel}` or `\num{3.7d10}\si{ \becquerel}`).

However, when I do this in equation mode there doesn't seem to be a way to create a space between the number and the unit. Am I missing something, or is this an inherent fault/problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
% International language package - allows use of special characters
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Line spacing package - allows user to set line spacing
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Graphics package - allows document to include various graphics files
\usepackage{chemformula}
% SI Unit package - allows for standard unit notation
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit\curie{Ci}

\begin{document}

% no spaces
\num{3.7d10}\si{\becquerel} \\

% space before unit
\num{3.7d10}\si{ \becquerel} \\

% space after number
\num{3.7d10} \si{\becquerel} \\

% no spaces
\begin{equation}
\num{1}\si{\becquerel} = \num{2.703d11}\si{\curie} \\
\end{equation}

% spaces before units
\begin{equation}
\num{1}\si{ \becquerel} = \num{2.703d11}\si{ \curie} \\
\end{equation}

% spaces after number
\begin{equation}
\num{1} \si{\becquerel} = \num{2.703d11} \si{\curie} \\
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you're typesetting a numerical quantity with units, you're supposed to use the `\SI` macro:

```
\SI{3.7d10}{\becquerel}
```

That effectively formats the first argument using `\num`, the second using `\si`, and inserts the proper spacing between them, even when typesetting an equation (i.e. when in math mode).

Normally spaces are ignored in math mode, so that you can write e.g. `3\times 10` or `3 \times 10` and the result will be the same.

Comment: Is it possible to change the spacing between the number and unit when using `\SI`?

Comment: @HélitonMartins yes, it's possible. You can do `\sisetup{number-unit-product=~}` to change the spacing to one non-breaking-space (~)

Answer (score 5):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, you can just use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \SI{1.234}{\m\per\square\s}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Another possibility (but not a recommended one) is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \num{1.234}\,\si{\m\per\square\s}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The second approach should only be used if you want alignment points at both the numbers and the units, as shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154243/align-math-explanation/154254#154254).