# Spacing problem with \usepackage{siunitx}

Tags: spacing, siunitx, units

im currently working on my Master's Thesis and i need siunitx for my SI units. The problem hereby is, that somehow my code doesnt generate the normally installed spaces between the number and the unit. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%Codierung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE, quantity-product = {,},exponent-product = \cdot]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE, per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}
\begin{document}

Example for SI unit: \SI{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}

\end{document}
```

The resulting sentence would be: 0.15m^3 g^-1

The space between the m^3 and g^-1 works somehow, but the one between the count and unit doesnt..It would be great, if someone could help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You should remove the `quantity-product = {,}` option. This sets the symbol to be used between the number and the unit, and is set to `\,` by default. In your MWE it does nothing because it should be set in `\sisetup` instead of passed as an option to the package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE]{siunitx}
\sisetup{exponent-product = \cdot,per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}
\begin{document}

Example for SI unit: \SI{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}

Example for SI unit: \SI[quantity-product = {,}]{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Unit spacing with siunitx in an equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160105/unit-spacing-with-siunitx-in-an-equation?rq=1)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
%Codierung
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[locale = DE, quantity-product = {,},exponent-product = \cdot]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE, per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}
\begin{document}

Example for SI unit:  \SI{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}

Another Example for SI unit:   \num{0.15}\,\si{\cubic\meter\per\gram}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much, both of you :) It worked finally! Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

By design (perhaps faulty, but it has been so for about 30 years), braces in the optional argument to `\usepackage` are essentially ignored, so what you get from

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  quantity-product = {,},
  exponent-product = \cdot,
]{siunitx}

\sisetup{locale = DE, per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

Example for SI unit: \SI{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}

\end{document}
```

(I reorganized a bit the preamble) is the same as

```
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  quantity-product = ,,
  exponent-product = \cdot,
]{siunitx}
```

and so `quantity-product` receives the empty value and there's an empty option that is ignored.

On the other hand, you don't want to set `quantity-product` to a comma, do you?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside,titlepage]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[
  locale = DE,
  quantity-product = \,,
  exponent-product = \cdot,
]{siunitx}

\sisetup{locale = DE, per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

Example for SI unit: \SI{0.15}{\cubic\meter\per\gram}

\end{document}
```

works well. But since you're going to use `\sisetup` anyway, just set all options there, without duplications:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
[...]
\sisetup{
  locale = DE,
  quantity-product = \,,
  exponent-product = \cdot,
  per-mode=reciprocal-positive-first,
}
```

I recommend to separate settings from package loading. The preamble becomes clearer and more easily maintained.

By the way, `quantity-product=\,` is the default, so there's no need to set it.