# How to do an equation correctly if the formula won't accept it?

Tags: equations, amsmath, mathtools

I do have two formulas in my text and the only way I could make them work is in a way with a lot of escaping commands. Now the formula looks correct but whenever I try to add an equation to make it referable Latex gives me an error. Also adding a label or other additional options doesn't help so far. Also the packages amsmath and mathtools are in use. The error actually appears on the line of the formula, not on the line of the equation itself. Does anybody have a solution? I'm thankful for any hints.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\begin{equation}
\[ -1 \leq \tau \leq 1 \]
%\end{equation}
```

Comment: A lot of escaping commands is the TeX users lot ;-) And `equation` allows one single line. If you need more, you have to use the `align` environment, for example. Loading `mathtools` is sufficient here!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it also does not work within one line. I get the same error -> \begin{equation} \[ -1 \leq \tau \leq 1 \] \end{equation}

Comment: Reading an introductory book on LaTeX clearly helps: Don't use `equation` and `\[` together. Use one and only one. You shall count only to one here ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Make sure you don't use both `\[...\]` *and* `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` simultaneously to encase your displayed equation. Use one or the other method, but not both at the same time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{eq:tau}
-1 \leq \tau \leq 1
\end{equation}
A cross-reference to equation (\ref{eq:tau}).
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works flawless, thanks a lot. Only the second formula gives me a warning, but it still works. And an additional question: My second formular contains full words. Although I put spaces between those words (and I also tried to hardcode them) those spaces won't be shown since the formula seems to think these are just variables. Do you also know a solution for that? -> \tau = \frac{(Persons of interest)

Comment: EDIT: The warning has been fixed. It was due to double assigning eq:tau of course, sorry about that.

Comment: The answer to your second question (about text in mathematics) is here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80165/how-to-place-text-on-fraction-for-accounting-formulas/80167#80167 . In general, it's not good to ask a followup question in a comment, or even in the original. Ask a new one.

Comment: @UserSoUndSo - To typeset a text string in math mode as text than as a collection of variables, write `\text{(Persons of interest)}`. (The `\text` macro requires the `amsmath` package.)